# How to merge specific lines and remove specific newlines from a text that's in the form of a changelog, using vim?

Tags: vim, merge, newlines

I have a changelog that's like this:

> version 1.90
>   <sup>*(1 newline)*</sup>
>   Released on 27 April 2014
>   <sup>*(2 consequent newlines)*</sup>
>
> Added feature x    ---> (first entry for 1.90)
>   <sup>*(1 newline between each entry)*</sup>
>   Fixed bug y
>
> Removed element z
>
> Updated file z    ----> (last entry for 1.90)
>   <sup>*(3 consequent newlines)*</sup>
>
> version 1.89

And I want:

1. To merge every two such lines:

   > version 1.90
   >
   > Released on 27 April 2014

   into :

   > version 1.90 (27 April 2014)

   and
2. to remove the following newlines:

   - all newlines between the entries,
     i.e. all newlines between 2 consequent newlines and 3 consequent lines
   - 1 of 2 newlines after the merged "version 1.90 (27 April 2014)"

The text is too long to convert it manually.
Thank you.

Comment: What (`:%substitute`) command have you tried, and with what are you struggling?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well:

```
g/^$/d
%s/\v^(version.*)\n(.*)/\r\1 (\2)\r
```

Comment: It did merge the merged the lines,    
but removed ALL entries in between the merged lines.

Comment: Yes, your updated suggestion works great.
Just one thing is left now, please:  
to add one more newline before each such line:   
`version 1.90 (Released on 27 April 2014)`

Comment: Would be: `%s/\v^(version.*)\n(.*)/\r\r\1 (\2)\r`

Comment: What did the trick was `:%s/\v^(Version.*)\n(.*)/\r\1`. Thanks a lot for your help!